# Bug: Reputation and background color are wrong

Tags: bug, status-norepro

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393238/hex-representaion-of-bytes-in-a-string).

User [Tahir Akram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170117/tahir-akram) has `13` reputation but in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393238/hex-representaion-of-bytes-in-a-string/1394540#1394540) the rep is `1` and the background color is white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are actually two different user accounts.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170244/tahir-akram) is the account with only one rep.

The 13 rep account has UserId **170117**.  The 1 rep account is UserId **170244**.

Comment: Ah, you're right.

Comment: So that would be a status-norepro then ;)